# how to configure Backbone.history + Requirejs with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, backbone.js

I have a Hybrid app using Cordova, Crosswalk, Backbone, Require and React, but the main components of this question are just Cordova and Backbone, specifically Backbone.history. I am using AMD loading.

Using backbone to navigate on the web is working flawlessly, but on mobile there are some very strange issues that happen.

If I don't configure things properly, the app will just crash when trying to load files after running Backbone.history.start()

here is my current start config:

```
Backbone.history.start({silent:false, pushState: true, hashChange: false, root: isMobile.any ? "android_asset/www/" : ""});
```

( setting the root to 'android_assets/www' is needed or else backbone will make require look for files at the root level, which is another issue I am having here )

In my current config, I do have the app technically working, but there are three main issues:

1) if I reload, all the loaded .js files are now treated as mime type plain/text, and I see this warning in the console. This does not break anything, but the warnings are annoying. This does not happen on the first load, only after reloading once I have started backbone history.

2) When loading the initial route, Backbone is looking for completely different pages on mobile than on desktop: The hash is the same ( "" ) on both, but the fragment changes to 'index.html' in the mobile version. In order to compensate for this, I had to add 'index.html' into my router's routes, which is a complete hack IMO.

desktop:

```
What is root? /
What is hash? 
What is fragment?
```

Mobile:

```
What is root? /android_asset/www/
What is hash? 
What is fragment? index.html
```

3) If I navigate to a custom route in the mobile app, then connect remotely with the chrome debugger and force a page refresh, the app will die because it can't find the FILE, not the route, and it dies. example message:

```
Application Error:

The file or directory could not be found. 
(file:///android_asset/www/showGame)
```

It's painfully obvious that Backbone.history is not being used correctly in my project. The issue is that cordova requires relative url's, and Backbone is doing a lot of work around parsing the url root string, the hash, fragment, and is not build to work in a relative only domain. What's really mind boggling is just how badly this is breaking everything when used. Does any one here have any experience, or advice, for configuring this properly? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

If I change the options in backbone.history.start to not use pushState, then reloading the app on a view page will work just fine. that problem is solved.

```
pushState: false, hashChange: false
```

I still get the warnings, but the trace for my fragments look better:

Mobile:

```
What is root? /android_asset/www/
What is hash? 
What is fragment?
```

I am still confused why I need to set the root to this path, I would prefer it if relative paths worked properly in Backbone.history and navigate. If there something more I can do to better address this?